Understanding Radicals as Intersections of Prime Ideals and as the Preimage of a Nilradical
I ran into a proposition that the radical $r(a)$ equals the intersection of the prime ideals containing $a$. Then it is said that the latter can be understood through the following result: Let $R$ be the nilradical of $A/a$, and let $\phi : A \to A/a$ be the quotient homomorphism. Then $r(a) = \phi^{-1}(R)$. I do not understand what the connection here is...

If $x+\mathfrak{a}$ is nilpotent in $A/\mathfrak a$, then exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ s.t. $0+\mathfrak a=(x+\mathfrak a)^n=x^n+\mathfrak a$, i.e. $x^n\in\mathfrak a$. If $\mathfrak P$ is a prime ideal in $A/\mathfrak a$, then $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak P)$ is a prime ideal in $A$ containing $\mathfrak a$. Please try to combine these two facts.

@Asigan; Thanks
